# "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy"

Tags: python, react-native, flask, cors

This is the full error: "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

I am aware of this post: [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe). I've tried virtually everything in this post, but I still come up with this error.

To give some context, I have a Python-Flask backend server with a React frontend server.

In my flask backend ('localhost:5000'), I've inserted the following code to handle the preflighted request given by a 'Content-Type: application/json' fetch request from the 'localhost:3000' react-native frontend server.

Flask backend:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'the-most-secret-key-in-the-history-of-secret-keys'
app.config['REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
app.config['REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True

CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}}) //this line (in theory) should handle preflighted requests such that a CORS error is NOT thrown.

DATABASE = 'buddy.db'
db = SqliteDatabase(DATABASE)

from app.models import User
with db:
    db.create_tables([User])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

React frontend:

```
try{
     const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/login', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:3000',
               'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
          credentials: 'include'            
     })
     const data = await response.json();
     console.log("JSON Message: " + data.message);
     setPostData(data.message);
     setPostError(data.error);
            
} catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
     setPostError(error);
}
```

I'm pretty new in terms of react-native, so I know that the way I fetch requests is not the cleanest. However, the part I'm stumped on is that all this code **worked** on a Windows computer (currently running on a mac), and it didn't throw a CORS-policy error as it does now.

On other posts, I've seen that the solution for most people was to handle the preflighted request triggered by "'Content-Type': 'application/json'", and I believe that I've done that in my flask-backend server:

```
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

However, this did not resolve my issue.

I've also tried clearing my cached images and files on Chrome, but the error still pops up.

Also, I saw something about running the following in [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000" \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization' \
    "https://the.sign_in.url"
```

I ran the following:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000" \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' \
    -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization' \
    "http://localhost:5000/login"
```

This returned the following:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: HEAD, GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
Vary: Origin
Content-Length: 0
Server: Werkzeug/2.0.3 Python/3.9.13
Date: Sat, 30 Dec 2023 16:56:39 GMT
```

It seems as though the correct headers are returned, but I'm not too sure--maybe this will help anyone in analyzing my issue.

Any advice/input is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Drop headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` from your request. Those headers are _response_ headers; they never belong in a request.

Comment: @jub0bs I dropped those headers from my request, but the same CORS error is still showing up.

Comment: So I replaced "localhost" with "127.0.0.1" in all occurrences and now the error is gone and the program works...?!?  Confused but not complaining :)